# Seek bar value changing for Android text view

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am working on an Android application in which I am using seek bar to show increment of the values. When I am moving the seek bar and stop the movement it gives me any value for example 2.3, which is fine.

However, I want to work the seek bar in this way that when I am moving the seek bar with the movement the numbers should also change. My code is given below:

```
start=-10;                              //you need to give starting value of SeekBar
end=10;                 //you need to give end value of SeekBar

SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
seek.setProgress(start_position);
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "discrete = "+String.valueOf(discrete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// To convert it as discrete value
float temp=progress;
float dis=end-start;
discrete=(start+((temp/100)*dis));
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are not setting your text or using Toast message in **onProgressChanged** which gets triggered everytime you move your seekbar so do it on your **onProgressChanged**

check the following code snippet:-

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// To convert it as discrete value
float temp=progress;
float dis=end-start;
discrete=(start+((temp/100)*dis));

 Log.e("value is -->",String.valueOf(discrete));
}
});
```

see that your toast works on **onStopTrackingTouch** which triggers when the movement stops.
use above and check your logcat for values and then you may perform your desired function.